# маленькая програмка в java и маленькая ошибка

Tags: java, swing

перехожу с СИ на JAVA...ява это какая то сплошная филология...в чем тут ошибка ? по нажатию кнопки должа выводится переменная, но почему то функция обработчик текстовый вывод выводит, а переменную не выводит? сообщает об ошибке, в чем дело ?

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent; 

import java.awt.event.ActionListener; 
import javax.swing.JButton; 
import javax.swing.JFrame; 
import javax.swing.*; 


public class Firshtclass
{ 
    int a=1; 
    int b=2;

    private static void Eve() // createAndShowGUI 
    { 
        JPanel windowContent= new JPanel(); 

        JLabel TextOut = new JLabel(); 
        windowContent.add(TextOut); 

        // JTextField field1 = new JTextField(20); 
        // windowContent.add(field1); 
        //................................................................... 
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("My First Calculator"); 
        frame.setContentPane(windowContent); 
        //................................................................... 
        JButton buttonUP = new JButton("Up"); 
        windowContent.add(buttonUP); 

        JButton buttonDOWN = new JButton("Down"); 
        windowContent.add(buttonDOWN); 

        //................................................................... 
        frame.setSize(400,100); 
        frame.setVisible(true); 
        //................................................................... 

        //Add action listener to button 
        buttonUP.addActionListener(new ActionListener() // UP 
        { 
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            { 
                TextOut.setText(a); 
            } 
        }); 

        buttonDOWN.addActionListener(new ActionListener() // DOWN 
        { 
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            { 
                TextOut.setText(b); 
            } 
        }); 
    }  // createAndShowGUI 

    public static void main(String[] args) // main 
    { 
        Eve(); 
    } // main 
}
```

Comment: Какая именно ошибка выводится?

Comment: ну я конечно не знаком с awt, но по аналогии с android'ом предположу что нельзя просто в `setText()` засунуть int, надо что то вроде этого использовать `setText(String.valueOf(a))`, либо `setText(""+a)`

Comment: напротив TextOut.setText(а); выводит "cannot make a static reference to the non-static field a"... но если вместо переменной а, вставить текст в скобках, то все выводится. Число, например TextOut.setText(45); тоже невыводится, а вот так TextOut.setText("текст"+45); выводится.....но переменная нивкаком виде невыводится....ясно...два аргумента ему нужно))

Comment: А в си разве можно вызывать не статический контент из статического метода?

Comment: ну так сделайте ваши aиb статичными, да и все

Comment: @ermak0ff не прокатит, функция принимает только String, надо еще как вы предлагали изначально.

Comment: не помогает если добавить статик, компилятор другую ошибку выдумывает

Comment: разобрался....нужно действительно сделать переменную статик, и хочешь -не хочешь должна быть + строковая переменная, так все выводится

Comment: @user198532 `и хочешь -не хочешь должна быть строковая переменная` да что Вы говорите, хотите сказать что если оставить интом и такая запись `setText(""+a)` не прокатит?

Comment: @ermak0ff `"" + a` преобразует `a` в строку. Так что либо переменная должна быть типа `String`, либо ее нужно преобразовать в строку.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ошибка компиляции программы на Java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/602194/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d0%bd%d0%b0-java)

Answer (score 4):

Я вижу несколько ошибок при компиляции.

**1.**

> Firstclass.java:43: error: non-static variable a cannot be referenced from a static context
>
> ```
>               TextOut.setText(a);
>                               ^
> ```

Нельзя использовать нестатические в статическом контектсте. Эта ошибка устраняется добавлением `static` к объявлению `a` и `b`:

```
static int a=1; 
static int b=2;
```

**2.**

> Firstclass.java:43: error: local variable TextOut is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final
>
> ```
>            TextOut.setText(a);
>            ^
> ```

Чтобы использовать (локальные) переменные внутри анонимного класса, нужно чтобы они были объявлены с модификатором `final`:

```
final JLabel TextOut = new JLabel();
```

<sup>Java 8 не требует объявления с `final`.</sup>

**3.**

> Firstclass.java:43: error: method setText in class JLabel cannot be applied to given types;
>
> ```
>            TextOut.setText(a);
>                   ^
> ```
>
> required: String
>    found: int
>    reason: actual argument int cannot be converted to String by method invocation conversion

`JLabel.setText` принимает только строки, поэтому `int` нужно *явно* преобразовать в строку, например `String.valueOf(a)`:

```
TextOut.setText(String.valueOf(a));
```

---

Все операции со Swing-компонентами должны выполняться *на Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)*, поэтому `main` должен выглядеть следующим образом:

```
public static void main(String[] args) // main 
{ 
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Eve(); 
        }
    });
} // main
```