# Почему происходит ошибка "non static variable cannot be referenced from a static context"?

Tags: java

Я изучаю `Java` по книге Head First Java.

В главе 4 выполнил задание, на мой взгляд верно (посмотрел ответы в книге - мое решение совпадает). Но, тем не менее, происходит ошибка при компиляции:

> non static variable cannot be referenced from a static context

в строке 10:

```
obs[x] = new Puzzle4b();
```

Код:

```
public class Puzzle4{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Puzzle4b[] obs = new Puzzle4b[6];
        
        int y=1;
        int x = 0;
        int result = 0;
        
        while(x < 6){
            obs[x] = new Puzzle4b();
            obs[x].ivar = y;
            y=y*10;
            x = x+1;
        }
        x = 6;
        
        while(x > 6){
            x = x-1;
            result = result + obs[x].doStuff(x);
        }
        
        System.out. print("Result "+ result);
        
    }
    class Puzzle4b {
        int ivar;
        public int doStuff(int factor){
            if(ivar>100){
                return ivar*factor;
            }
            else {
                return ivar*(5 -  factor);
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

То, что выше - выдает пустой результат (ноль). А должно выводить `543345`.

В чем заключается моя ошибка?

Comment: Как не странно, этот код у меня выполнился без каких-либо ошибок.

Comment: Я запускаю вручную через  javac, версия 1.8.0_31

Comment: Вы нам показываете не тот код, который запускаете.
Если вы запускаете компилятор из командной строки, то проверте что все файлы в редакторе сохранены.

Comment: Ну, тогда, думаю самое время переходить на IDE ;)) На мой взгляд, использование cmd никак не помогает изучению и не добавляет крутости, а просто создает неудобства и тратит время ;)

Comment: В приведённом коде указанная ошибка возникнуть не может. А вот логические ошибочки есть.

Comment: Допишите кстати в сообщение строку, которой запускаете файл

Comment: Да, я ошибся, не тот код вам показал, исправил в первом посте. .

Comment: javac Puzzle4.java - вот как я запускаю компилятор

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ошибка возникает потому, что Вы пытаетесь создать экземпляр внутреннего класса (*inner class*) в статическом методе внешнего класса (*outer class*) – так делать нельзя.

Экземпляр внутреннего класса можно создать только в **нестатическом** методе внешнего класса, иными словами – имея экземпляр внешнего класса.

Если Вы хотите создать экземпляр класса `Puzzle4b` в статическом методе внешнего класса, то класс `Puzzle4b` необходимо объявить статическим (*static nested class*):

```
static class Puzzle4b {
    int ivar;
    public int doStuff(int factor){
        if(ivar>100){
            return ivar*factor;
        }
        else {
            return ivar*(5 -  factor);
        }
    }
}
```

Подробнее можете почитать в любой (лучше классической) книге по Java в главе, где описываются внутренние классы.

> То, что выше - выдает пустой результат (ноль). А должно 543345

Посмотрите внимательно на фрагмент кода, где Вы изменяете переменную `result`:

```
x = 6;

while(x > 6) {
    x = x-1;
    result = result + obs[x].doStuff(x);
}
```

Цикл `while(x > 6) {...}` не выполняется ни разу, так как `6 > 6 == false`, следовательно, при выводе `result` на консоль, в нем будет то значение, которым Вы инициализировали эту переменную изначально:

```
int result = 0;
```

Comment: Точно, надо было условие x>0 ставить! Тогда бы мой первый вариант работал успешно, когда класс  я вытащил наружу.

Comment: Странно , но про static в книге еще ни слова не было, видимо задание некорректное.

Comment: Получается из статического метода нельзя вызывать нестатический. Но я же вызвал obs[x] = new Puzzle4b(); в static void main, а class Puzzle4b не в нем находится. Почему так?

Comment: @AndreyVladislavovich, Я очень скептически отношусь к книгам из серии Head First, по-моему по Java лучше почитать Шилдта.

Comment: @AndreyVladislavovich, Все что я говорил – я говорил про **внутренние** классы. Если Вы вынесли класс `Puzzle4b` куда-либо из класса `Puzzle4`, то класс `Puzzle4b` внутренним уже не является.

Answer (score 0):

Джава - объектно-ориентированный язык. Через new ты создаешь экземпляры объектов некоего класса. Но класс - это тоже объект по сути, который занимает место в памяти и на который можно получить ссылку.

Когда программа пишет .class файл, она делит все переменные в классе на две части. static будут записаны в объект класса. Этот тип переменных увеличит размер самого класса. Объект класса - он один в памяти и грузится один раз и на все время работы. Соответственно и статическая переменная - одна на класс и соответственно - одна на все созданные объекты данного класса.

Не-статические переменные будут записываться в порожденные объекты, для каждого порожденного объекта будет свой независимый набор этих переменных, которыми можно манипулировать независимо друг от друга.

Дык вот. В момент старта программы загружается только класс. Ни одного экземпляра объекта нет, пока не создашь через new. Не-статичных переменных, которые храняться в объектах, тоже нет еще и нет для них места в оперативной памяти. Их неоткуда читать и некак писать. Поэтому и ругается программа, что ты пытаешься обратиться к нестатичным переменным из статичной функции.

P.S. Вот для примера, ты автоматизируешь единую диспетчерскую систему аэропортов страны. Удельная плотность керосина - единая величина для всех аэропортов. То есть, от объема купленного топлива можно посчитать его вес в любой момент, ничего не зная о конкретном аэропорте. Плотность - статичная величина. А длина ВПП и количество стоянок на перроне - для каждого аэропорта своя. Пока ты не создашь экземпляр аэропорта через new и не загрузишь инфу из базы данных - ты не сможешь оперировать этими величинами. Без выбранного аэропорта количество стоянок - абстрактное понятие, не имеющее никакого смысла.

Comment: Вопрос почитайте внимательно. В коде нет обращений к нестатическим объектам из статических методов. Ошибка к этому коду явно не имеет никакого отношения.

Comment: Спасибо, про статические классы очень хорошо рассказали. В книге правда еще ни слова про них не было.