# Ошибка "non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context"

Tags: java

Учусь программировать по учебнику и попытался понять принципы ООП. Написал следующий код в Main.java:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main (String [] args) {

        Dog chakki = new Dog();
        Dog muhtar = new Dog();
        muhtar.bark();
        chakki.setAge(12);
        System.out.println(muhtar.getAge());        
        System.out.println(chakki.getAge());            
    }   
}
```

И в той же директории создал Dog.java и код из неё:

```
public class Dog {

    private static int age = 10;

    public static void bark() { 
        System.out.println("Gaf Gaf");
    }

    public static int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public static void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }   
}
```

И когда пытался скомпилировать в командной строке выдаёт ошибку:

```
.\Dog.java:19: error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context
                this.age = age;

            ^
1 error
```

Вопросы:

1. Почему так происходит?
2. И когда я пытался скомпилировать без методов, просто меняя значение age напрямую, то у меня менялись значения обоих объектов muhtar и chakki, то есть они были равны последнему значению. Отсюда и вопрос почему значения переменных двух объектов(muhtar, chakki) были равны последнему измененному значению. Ведь я создал класс Dog и объявил 2 объекта(muhtar, chakki), и думал что значения будут для этих объектов отдельными и разными. Но, видимо, я что-то не так понял.

Помогите разобраться и понять)))

Comment: уберите слово `static` (все четыре) из кода класса `Dog` - оно там не к месту

Comment: Связанный, но не дубликат (там про inner class): [Ошибка компиляции программы на Java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/602194/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d0%bd%d0%b0-java)

Comment: Хорошо. Первый раз задал вопрос, не знал о правилах оформления дословно)) И я убрал слово static везде из класса Dog и всё заработало)) Спасибо большое, значит дело в static. Пойду почитаю побольше о нём)))

Comment: @Balapan дописал про причины ошибки, гляньте. Если что-то непонятным осталось — спрашивайте, объясню.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Хотел спросить в той похожей проблеме, которую вы мне скинули, в ответах было упоминание насчёт книги. В данный момент я изучаю по Head First Javа, но человек, который давал ответ рекомендовал Java Шилдта книгу. Стоит ли переходить на Шилдта? Если я хочу получить более качественные знания?

Comment: @Balapan Шилдт хорош. Но я думаю, что книга — не главное. Важнее 1) постоянная практика и 2) ревью кода — это когда вы показываете свой код более опытным разработчикам и они вам рекомендуют, что и где можно было сделать лучше. Тут можно задавать такие вопросы с меткой [tag:инспекция-кода].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Чем отличается static и не-static

Когда вы объявляете переменную как `static`, она принадлежит всему классу целиком, а не каждому объекту. И существует эта переменная в единственном экземпляре, сколько бы ни было экземпляров класса.

Вот это — возраст всех собак вообще. У вас на двух собак — один возраст. Не годится, потому что у собак бывают разные возраста.

```
private static int age = 10;
```

А этот метод устанавливает возраст всех собак разом:

```
public static void setAge...
```

А нужен возраст каждой отдельно взятой собаки из класса собак:

```
private int age = 10;
```

### Причины ошибки “non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context”

Далее: `this.age` означает значение переменной `age` в данном конкретном (`this`) экземпляре класса. Но вы выполняете этот код в статическом методе, принадлежащем классу. Поскольку метод относится ко всему классу, конкретные экземпляры ему неизвестны.

Поэтому возникает ошибка “non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context”. Дословно: вы обращаетесь к нестатической переменной, но делаете это <s>без уважения</s> из статического контекста, и это не имеет смысла.

Comment: Понял) Спасибо еще раз

Comment: Ну вот, модераторы стали отбирать хлеб у джавистов) [meta-tag:модераторский-произвол]

Comment: @ЮрийСПб зашёл в метку с вами пообщаться, так-то почти не контактируем )))

Comment: И 45 репутации украли))) Вот выберут меня в этот раз модератором - буду у @Nicolas Chabanovsky просить функционал на сайте по разграничению сфер влияния для модераторов)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб так вы давайте, выдвигайтесь.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, сегодня днём выдвинусь) Судя по кол-ву уже выдвинувшихся конкуренция таки будет. Я даже уже сомневаться начинаю в своей победе - там пара человек есть достойных, а мандатов, как обычно, мало(

Comment: @ЮрийСПб ну вы-то бывалый кандидат )

Comment: Но при этом и "молодежь" в наше время чрез чур политически активная(

Comment: @ЮрийСПб там вся молодежь под сорок )

Comment: @NickVolynkin, оттого она у меня и в кавычках)